How can I make my computer go into "sleep" mode when no apps are in use, without shutting down display
I want to save power consumption and preserve my components, without locking my screen and without shutting down the display. Basically just show the desktop but running with minimum power. It could also not be automatic, I don't mind pressing a button or entering a command.
CPU usage is low, but not low enough for my taste (8-10% idle).
I'm using a laptop as a "dekstop pc", so that's why I don't want to make it sleep and then having to open the lid. That part seems dumb, but if you saw my setup you would understand.
